# How do I enter a continuous variable as a random effect in a linear mixed effects model?

Tags: mixed-model

I collected data on the growth of juvenile fish from 4 different types of crosses using multiple distinct family blocks and I am trying to see if cross type has an effect on growth using linear mixed effects models. I have one fixed factor (Length), 3 categorical random factors (sire, dam and sire/dam interaction) and a continuous random factor (density per tank). As I am relatively new to R and new to mixed effects models, I was wondering if I would have to code the continuous random factor in R differently from the categorical random factors using lme4?

So far I have

```
model5=lmer(Length~(1|Dam)+(1|Sire)+(1|Sire:Dam)+(1|Density))
model6=lmer(Length~Cross+(1|Dam)+(1|Sire)+(1|Sire:Dam)+(1|Density))
```

is density coded in properly, or would I have to alter it due to the fact that it is a continuous variable?

Comment: Continuous random factors don't make sense to me. See Douglas Bates, [_lme4: Mixed-effects modeling with R_](http://lme4.r-forge.r-project.org/lMMwR/lrgprt.pdf), pages 1-2: random (or fixed) effects parameters are associated with the levels of _categorical_ covariates.

Comment: You can try to convert it to categorical variable: `cut(Density,5)`. But I agree it doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 14):

I'll elaborate on what I think Sergio meant in his comment.

A random effect is always associated with a categorical variable. This categorical variable will most often divide the observations into different observational units (this could for instance be `Dam` in your data set as it seems reasonable to assume that observations from the same dam are more alike than from different dams. Using something like `(1|Dam)` will give you a random intercept on that variable.

Using a continuous predictor like `Density` you can get a random slope on the predictor. Then you'll have to use `(Density|Dam)` in your model formulae. This will give you a (random) slope, i.e. effect of `Density`, for each level of `Dam`.

What you're doing in the above code is forcing `Density` to be used as a categorical predictor, i.e. making a random intercept for each level (value) of `Density`. This is probably not what you want.